# Streamripper quality

Tags: audio-recording, icecast

We use streamripper 1.64.6 (http://streamripper.sourceforge.net) to record archives from our Icecast 2.4.4 stream. Does anyone know if streamripper does anything to lower the quality of the audio recordings? The stream source sounds so much crisper and live than the archive we record. Almost like it is compressing or normalizing in some way. If I pull up one of the archives, you can see the audio appear normalized. But I don't see settings for controlling this behavior in the streamripper.ini or command-line options. I like the simplicity of streamripper, but are there better alternatives?